# Forms authentication is not working on Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer, forms-authentication

i cannot login to my MVC3 Web Site located on the server with Forms Authentication from Internet Explorer.

My ASP.NET MVC3 web site using forms authentication. I got problems on authentication when using the site via Internet Explorer.

If i m using the site from local (Development environment or From hosting server machine with remote desktop connection) login works with no problems. But when i try to login to the web site located on the server from my local machine, i cannot get past the login page.

Tried changing ie security and privacy options to allow cookies, added my domain to trustes domains. But still i cannot get past the login page.

Here is my login code after all the authentication checks (User name, password etc.)

```
...
string userDataString = userid.ToString();

HttpCookie authCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(username, rememberme);
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
FormsAuthenticationTicket newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(ticket.Version, ticket.Name, ticket.IssueDate, ticket.Expiration, ticket.IsPersistent, userDataString);

authCookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);
Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnurl) &&
    returnurl.Length > 1 &&
    returnurl.StartsWith("/") &&
    !returnurl.StartsWith("//") &&
    !returnurl.StartsWith("/\\") &&
    returnurl.IndexOf("XMLHttpRequest") < 0)
{
    return Redirect(returnurl);
}
else
{
    return Redirect("/");
}

...
```

and web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
...
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="*******" connectionString="******" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="/Error/General">
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="/Error/NoAccess" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Error/NotFound" />
    </customErrors>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Authentication" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <machineKey validationKey="*********" decryptionKey="**************" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />

    <membership defaultProvider="TestMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="TestMembershipProvider" type="Test.Helpers.TestMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="TestContext" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="TestRoleProvider" cacheRolesInCookie="true" cookieName="AppRoles" cookieTimeout="20" cookiePath="/" cookieRequireSSL="false" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" cookieProtection="All">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="TestRoleProvider" type="Test.Helpers.TestRoleProvider" connectionStringName="TestContext" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

    ...

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

</configuration>
```

Any thoughts would be appriciated, because i run out of ideas.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been a know bug of ie10 ([IE10 User-Agent causes ASP.Net to not send back Set-Cookie (IE10 not setting cookies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983732/ie10-user-agent-causes-asp-net-to-not-send-back-set-cookie-ie10-not-setting-coo)).

I have installed this(http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088) hotfix to server and the issue is resolved. But beware this fix may / will reset your iis extension settings and Wildcard aplication maps.

So if you are using MVC follow the instructions listed on the answer to this([MVC3 publishing and IIS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391804/mvc3-publishing-and-iis-6)) question after installing the hotfix. To be able to fix the "Directory Listing Denied" error.

Comment: Seems web.config fix is right fix for me... your SO link here helped locating it.. thanks :-)